# How to get count of records in details section using crystal report c# windows form?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I know how to get total count of records that is displayed either in 
  Report header or Report footer by using "Summary" After right click on design
  and point to Insert then we will find.

But when i tried to insert this into Page header or Page footer it won't 
  display at all. Now i want to display total record count for every page (Just
  place in page footer). How to do this?

I tried below code after searching:

In details :

```
whileprintingrecords; 
numbervar x; 
x := x +1;
```

In page header and page footer also i have mentioned but it displays 
 whileprintrecords directly on to the report.

Note :I have entered the above 3 lines of code in text filed. Because i don't
       know how to write the code in crystal report.

Can you tell me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reset the variable in header.

```
Global numbervar x;
x:=0;
```

Now write your formula in formula filed and place as a last field in detail section

```
Global numbervar x;
x:=x+databasefield;
```

Now in page footer write below

```
Global numbervar x;
x
```

Comment: where is formula field? can your explain your above code? Is it right to write the header code in text filed? Then in detail section In which i will write the code? and footer In which i will write code?Is it text field? please explain briefly.I am new to this one. Thanks

Comment: In crystal report to the right side in field explorer you will find formula fields..right click on that and create  a new one...there write the formulas after that drag and drop on to report

Comment: i did same thing now but it doesn't display total count here in footer section and as well detail section too. I added in formula field after that i dragged any thing wrong?

Comment: This is dispalyed in header like 0.00 and in detail added my id column is added with my previous id column then it gives count. This is not my approach i want count of records in details section. After that displayed in my footer page but in footer page also shown like 0.00

Comment: Did you place in report footer or page footer?

Comment: Yes siva but i didn't use your code even i didn't check because what i posted in detail section those code only i used but i don't know how to create a formula field so what u said the way of creating formula field that is right. Definitely i will accept your answer once check ur code. Thanks